PM2 starts correctly in GitHub Actions workflow but not in SSH session – how to ensure consistent PM2 context?
on github actions this file is executing successfully by starting pm2 instance as service but when in login to my ssh server and run command "pm2 ls" it does not list any pm2 instance as service.
here is my github actions workflow yml file:
name: Deploy Backend Test Environment
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - backend-dev
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    defaults:
      run:
        # shell: bash -l {0}
        working-directory: backend
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 16
    
    - name: Install PM2 globally
      run: npm install -g pm2

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps
      
    - name: starting backend
      run: npm run pm2dev

here are my package.json scripts which are being used in above workflow file:
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.prod nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f .env.dev nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js",
    "list": "pm2 ls",
    "pm2": "pm2 delete 3fi-backend || true && PORT=3001 env-cmd -f .env.prod pm2 start server.js --name 3fi-backend",
    "pm2dev": "pm2 delete 3fi-backend-dev || true && PORT=3002 env-cmd -f .env.dev pm2 start server.js --name 3fi-backend-dev"
  },


on github actions this file is executing successfully by starting pm2
instance as service but when in login to my ssh server and run command
"pm2 ls" it does not list any pm2 instance as service.

so i updated these in workflow file:
- name: Start backend
      run: |
        export PM2_HOME=$(pwd)/.pm2
        npm run pm2dev
        pm2 save --force

here are pm2 logs on github actions cli after adding export PM2_HOME=$(pwd)/.pm2
Run export PM2_HOME=$(pwd)/.pm2
  
Lifecycle scripts included in backend-3fi@1.0.0:
  start
    env-cmd -f .env.prod nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js
available via npm run-script:
  dev
    env-cmd -f .env.dev nodemon --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js
  list
    pm2 ls
  pm2
    pm2 delete 3fi-backend || true && PORT=3001 env-cmd -f .env.prod pm2 start server.js --name 3fi-backend
  pm2dev
    pm2 delete 3fi-backend-dev || true && PORT=3002 env-cmd -f .env.dev pm2 start server.js --name 3fi-backend-dev
                        -------------
__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
 _\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
  _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
   _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
    _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
     _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
        _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__
                          Runtime Edition
        PM2 is a Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
                     with a built-in Load Balancer.
                Start and Daemonize any application:
                $ pm2 start app.js
                Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
                $ pm2 start api.js -i 4
                Monitor in production:
                $ pm2 monitor
                Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
                $ pm2 startup
                To go further checkout:
                http://pm2.io/
                        -------------
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/landing_page_v2/landing_page_v2/backend/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Saving current process list...
[PM2] Successfully saved in /home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/landing_page_v2/landing_page_v2/backend/.pm2/dump.pm2

it seems on github actions context of pm2 home is
/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/landing_page_v2/landing_page_v2/backend/.pm2/dump.pm2

but when in run "pm2 resurrect" on ssh server i get following logs:
[PM2] Resurrecting
[PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/ubuntu/.pm2/dump.pm2
[PM2][ERROR] Failed to read dump file in /home/ubuntu/.pm2/dump.pm2
[PM2] Restoring processes located in /home/ubuntu/.pm2/dump.pm2.bak
[PM2][ERROR] Failed to read dump file in /home/ubuntu/.pm2/dump.pm2.bak
[PM2][ERROR] No processes saved; DUMP file doesn't exist

so i am unable to access my backend,which is running on http port.
